Parole che terminino in -ar
I have a question about the use of subjunctive in this phrase "Parole che terminino in -ar " which is the title on a webpage.
Why do they use subjunctive in this phrase? Should it not be "terminano"?

Where is that webpage? It looks like either a typo or an attempt to phrase it in a way that wants to be elegant but is ultimately meaningless.

In that case, it should be parole che terminano in -ar. It seems they are using the congiuntivo mood for no reason. (That seems, without more context.)
